# Need suggestions to go with Jenkins master-Slave setup or not?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a 4-5 java projects build procedure to be configured as CI using Jenkins. Whether it will be time saving to build some/all projects on different machines(connected as Jenkins slaves)?

Are there some any other benefits of Jenkins Master-Slave configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offloading work to build agents is a very good idea as it keeps load away from the master. This allows you to build more projects in parallel (esp. with dynamic agents launched in some cloud environment).

Further, it makes the systems easier to maintain, as e.g. the Java version/setup of your build agents required to build and test your application does not interfere with the Jenkins master machine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your response.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Please use the checkmark on the left of my answer to mark your question as solved.